# CSS z-index not working with position relative

Tags: css, z-index

I am having no luck with getting `z-index` to work. While this all seems pretty simple. I *just* need to show some content overwriting some other content. This is to create a simple dropdown control, so that the dropped down menu is temporarily shown without the next content moving down, and later back up.

Here is my code, simplified, and stand-alone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Z-Axis</title>
    <style>
        #main_div {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 0;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_div">
        <p>line 1 of text</p>
        <p>line 1 of text</p>
        <p>line 1 of text</p>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>5</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>20</li>
        </ul>
        <p>line 2 of text</p>
        <p>line 3 of text</p>
        <p>line 4 of text</p>
        <p>line 5 of text</p>
        <p>line 6 of text</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see, I took care of creating a parent `stacking context` in the main-div, but this did not help. When I run the above in Firefox or Chrome, the dropdown list is shown, and the lines 2-6 are pushed down the page, instead of hiding behind the dropdown list.

The `position` has to be relative, because this stuff will be a React component, and be positioned somewhere in a larger page. The dropdown list should be right below Line1, and lines 2-6 should be hiding on a lower z-index plane.

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr, codepen or alternative?

Comment: I expect you want to have "absolute" as the second position, or it none of the other values serve a purpose

Comment: its not working on `relative` postion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thing you got wrong was `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute`. I changed it and now it works. `position: relative` makes it only, well, relative, not render regardless or other DOM elements.

I added `background: red` so the effect is better visible.

Your `z-index` works just fine, but element is still rendered respecting other DOM elements.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> - **relative**:
>     **The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document**, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static.
>     This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. Its effect on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.
> - **absolute**:
>     **The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout**. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

#### Key part

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

#### Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Z-Axis</title>
    <style>
        #main_div {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 0;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .list-wrapper {
          position: relative;
        }
        .dropdown {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
      <div class="list-wrapper">
        <p>line 1 of text</p>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>5</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>20</li>
        </ul>
        <p>line 2 of text</p>
        <p>line 3 of text</p>
        <p>line 4 of text</p>
        <p>line 5 of text</p>
        <p>line 6 of text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see. But the dropdown should not be positioned absolute to the html page. I added two more head lines, and what I see is that these are overwritten. Do I need to create another parent element to which the dropdown can position absolute?

Comment: @Roland: I edited my snippet. Added new wrapper with `position: relative` and some content above the list. Does it suffice your needs now? :). Please let me know.

Comment: Great! In fact, `div id=main_div` can be removed.

Comment: I didn't want to mess around your code too much. ;). Nice to hear I could help.

Comment: I have seen so many posts on this issue, but now finally the concept of parent context has been sorted out.